# Correct use of both for a pair of adjectives with a singular or an uncountable noun

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, distributive-determiners

I would like to know which of the following sentences is correct:

- we investigate a new problem, where both a decisional and a switching variable **is** a control at disposal of the agents;
- we investigate a new problem, where both a decisional and a switching variable **are** controls at disposal of the agents.

I think that the first is the correct one. Indeed, I think that when "both" is used with two nouns, then the verb is always plural. However, if you just have one singular or uncountable noun and use "both" for a pair of adjectives, then the verb is singular. Is it right?

Thank You

Comment: A little off. If you have a car painted red and blue, your one red and blue **car is** pretty. If you have two cars, red and blue, your **cars are** different colors. Your decisional and switching variables seem plural. Or is the one variable both?

Comment: Both of two things _are_, regardless of the presence of adjectives.

Comment: Ok, so the second one is correct. Thank you!